# how to save data/records from html form to DB2 database

Tags: windows, db2

this is my html form

```
<form class="form-horizontal"  id="myCredantials" >

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username : </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tbUsername" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email : </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">
                <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="tbEmail" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gender : </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">

                <select id="cbmGender">
                <option value="-1">Gender</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date : </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tbDate">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price : </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">            
                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" value="0"  id="tbPrice" placeholder="Prices">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Perc % : </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">            
                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" value="0"  id="tbPercentage" placeholder="%">
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password : </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="tbPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password : </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">
                <input type="password"  class="form-control" id="tbConfirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm">
            </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary " id="btnSubmit" onclick="onSave()" value="Save" >
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary " id="btnClear" onclick="onClearError()" value="Remove Error" >
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary " id="btnGet" onclick="doGet()" value="Get" >
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary " id="btnGet" onclick="doPost()" value="Post" >
            </div>

    </div>
    <div style="width:700px;">
    <table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="700"  id="tbl_Credantials">

        </table>

    </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You would post the form to a server side script that connected to the database and inserted the values, this is too broad a question.

Comment: Agree with @AlexK., although it may help if you posted the javascript source for the `onSave()` function, too.